# Animated mosaic

Tags: post-processing, software-recommendation

I want to make sort of an animated mosaic of about 25 photos.
Starting from a white background and having the photos fade in one by one untill the entire canvas is filled.

Can anyone recommend an application that'll let me do this?
I've tried Fotomagico but that only allows up to 6 images per slide.

Comment: What is this for? A video? A presentation? A screen saver? A kiosk? A photoframe? More info will help the decision. Eg: for a video I know you can do this with Adobe Aftereffects (manually). Same with Powerpoint (can be done manually). I don't know about the other use cases, but some research and I am sure we can help you get what you want.

Comment: I'm quite interested in the answer to this in relation to screensavers in particular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this with Microsoft Powerpoint 2007 on Windows. That allows you to create a slideshow and export it as a movie. Setting the slide size to 1280x720 makes it HD. (has to be the Windows version, Powerpoint for OS X lacks some options to do this).

Comment: FYI, The Windows 8 photo app slideshow does precisely what you are asking for.